# How to change focus to pygame window?

Tags: python, pygame, focus

I'm trying to make a game with `pygame` where at the end a `tkinter` message pops up showing a game over message and an option to play again.

When I press the 'play again' button, the player sprite doesn't move at all when pressing the key.

And then I found out that it was happening because, after I press on the message box button, it was not changing its focus to the active `pygame` window.

It would be helpful if someone could tell me how I can change the focus window.

Comment: If you are trying to create a game over screen, I would recommend doing it in the same window as your pygame loop, and not using tkinter to create a separate window

Comment: Are you importing an external python script which has the `messagebox` and displaying it, or are your making it inside of you `pygame` script and there also quite some Q on SO about this, take a look at those too

Comment: Be sure to call `root.quit()` in tkinter to exit the loop. Where is the focus after the message box closes?

Comment: @Mike67 it focuses back on my text editor Sublime Text

Comment: @CoolCloud I'll see that and try again

Comment: Can you show us your code? That way, we can test it and see why your problem is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

**If you use Windows**, you can use the [**`win32gui`**](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui.html) module and more particularly the [`SetFocus()`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__SetFocus_meth.html) method.

For example, the program below, inspired by [this](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/10/20/pywin32-how-to-bring-a-window-to-front/) page, creates a `tkinter` window and a `pygame` window and brings them to front alternatively.

```py
# -------------------------------
# initialise the front() function

import win32gui

def windowEnumerationHandler(hwnd, windows):
    windows.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))

results = []
windows = []
win32gui.EnumWindows(windowEnumerationHandler, windows)

def front(win_name):
    for i in windows:
        if i[1] == win_name:
            win32gui.ShowWindow(i[0],5)
            win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(i[0])
            break

# ------------------------
# create the pygame window

import pygame

class PygameWindow:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
        pygame.display.set_caption(self.name)

    def to_front(self):
        front(self.name)

pygame_window = PygameWindow('This is the pygame window')

# -------------------------
# create the tkinter window

import tkinter

class TkinterWindow:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.window.title(self.name)

    def to_front(self):
        front(self.name)

tkinter_window = TkinterWindow('This is the tkinter window')

# ------------------------------------------
# main loop - switch between the two windows

from time import sleep
while True:
    sleep(1)
    pygame_window.to_front()
    sleep(1)
    tkinter_window.to_front()
    
    # update the tkinter window to make it to stay visible
    tkinter_window.window.update()
```